# Adding a database field as part of a hyperlink url in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to add a database field as part of a hyperlink url to a jrxml file.  In the reference box I have

```
"https://mywebsite.com/cart.php?a=add&pid=3&customfield[3]=<insert field>"
```

I need to replace "insert field" with the field site_url.  I've tried just inserting the field name

```
<$F{site_url}>
```

but I get this

```
<((java.lang.String)field_site_url.getValue())>
```

instead of what's in the field.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User216...,

Here is how I create my parameterized hyperlinks to other reports in iReport:

- Right-click on the field to hyperlink and click "Hyperlink"
- Change the hyperlink type to "ReportExecution"
- Click the link parameters tab
- Click the add button
- The link parameter name is the parameter in the destination report
- The parameter class name defines the parameter class
- And finally, the value expression is the value to pass, in your case $F{site_url}